# Better algorithm to check if a number is neither a prime nor a power of a single prime

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have the following program where *t* can take the value from 1 to 100000 and *n* can take the value 1 to 10^9.

```
#define MAX 10000000

using namespace std;

unordered_set<long long int> s;

bool morethanone(long long int n)
{
    long long int check=0;
    for(unordered_set<long long int>::iterator it=s.begin();it!=s.end();it++)
    {
        if(n%(*it)==0)
            check++;
        if(check>1)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool isprime(long long int n)
{
    if(n%2==0)
        return false;
    for(long long int i=3;i<=sqrt(n);i+=2)
        if(n%i==0)
            return false;
    return true;
}

int main() 
{
s.insert(2);
s.insert(3);
for(long long int i=4;i<=MAX;i++)
{
        if(isprime(i))
            s.insert(i);
}

long long int t,n;
scanf("%lld",&t);
for(long long int test=0;test<t;test++)
{
    scanf("%lld",&n);
    if(n==1||s.find(n)!=s.end())
        cout<<"Santa\n";
    else if(morethanone(n))
        cout<<"Santa\n";
    else
        cout<<"Banta\n";
}

return 0;
}
```

Basically the program generates primes till 10^9 and prints "Santa" if the number given is a prime or a power of a single prime or 1.

The above program works for MAX=10^6 but shows "Terminated due to timeout" for any value beyond that.

Comment: So your question is actually that you want to optimize your code, since you get a timeout for too large numbers on whatever site you picked that challenge from and not an issue with datatypes?

Comment: Google the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: @molbdnilo : For the Sieve, I'll need to initialize some data structure of size 10^9 initially. And no data structure seems to be able to hold that much without compromising on the access time.

Comment: @Bharg Smart people just sieve blocks at a time.  If you don't feel like being smart, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/ can store 10^9 bits in 128 MB of RAM.

Comment: @Bharg that datastructure would most definitely not be of size 10^9. The precise number would be 50847534, as a short lookup on the [prim number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Table_of_.CF.80.28x.29.2C_x.2Flog_x.2C_and_li.28x.29) shows.

Comment: `sqrt(n)` can be time consuming, so *move it off* the loop: `int threshold = (int) (sqrt(n) + 1); for(long long int i=3;i<=threshold;i+=2)...`

Answer (score 1):

You want to determine if *n* can be written *p<sup>k</sup>* with *p* prime and *k* > 0 integral.

Henri Cohen describes an answer in Algorithm 1.7.5 of his book *A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory*. He exploits Fermat’s Little Theorem and the witness to the compositeness of *n* that is found by the Miller-Rabin primality tester. Cohen proves that if *a* is a witness to the compositeness of *n*, in the sense of the Miller-Rabin test, then gcd(*a<sup>n</sup>* − *a*, *n*) is a non-trivial divisor of *n* (that is, it is between 1 and *n*).

I reduce this idea to Python code at http://ideone.com/cNzQYr and give a fuller explanation at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2015/03/13/prime-power-predicate/). Here is the interesting code from ideone.com because Stack Overflow won't let me post without it; go there to see the rest:

```
# returns p,k such that n=p**k, or 0,0
# assumes n is an integer greater than 1
def primePower(n):
    def checkP(n, p):
        k = 0
        while n > 1 and n % p == 0:
            n, k = n / p, k + 1
        if n == 1: return p, k
        else: return 0, 0
    if n % 2 == 0: return checkP(n, 2)
    q = n
    while True:
        a = findWitness(q)
        if a == 0: return checkP(n, q)
        d = gcd(pow(a,q,n)-a, q)
        if d == 1 or d == q: return 0, 0
        q = d
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many advanced ways to calculate primes quickly, but a simple way to improve your code is to only check if the next candidate number is divisible by one of the primes you found so far. When you keep the primes in a data structure that allows for sorting you can stop once you reach a prime larger than the square root of the candidate number.

As mentioned in the comments, sieving in blocks is also possible and can be combined with the above improvement. Right now you are only checking odd numbers which is actually sieving with a block size of 2. If you checked that the candidate is not divisible by 3 you can check with block size 6. This would mean omitting every even position in the block and positions with a (one-based) index divisible by 3, so only index 1 and 5. And so on...

Checking whether a number is the power of a single prime can also be improved. Once you find one prime it is divisible by, check whether it is a power of this prime (write another method) and stop immediately.